# Toolbar menu inflating issue

Tags: android, menu, android-menu

I have created menu in toolbar.But sometime menu icon is visible and sometime not visible when activity load.and i also want to implement multiselection of submenu

here is my menu.xml file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/language_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_language_white"
        android:title="Language"
        app:showAsAction="always">

        <menu>

        <group
            android:id="@+id/group2"
            android:checkableBehavior="all"
            >
            <item
                android:id="@+id/submenu1"
                android:title="English"
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                app:showAsAction="never"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/submenu2"
                android:title="Hindi"
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                app:showAsAction="never"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/submenu3"
                android:title="Gujarati"
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                app:showAsAction="never"
                />
        </group>

    </menu>

</item>
```

and here is my java code for inflating menu

```
Toolbar toolbarMain = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
setSupportActionBar(toolbarMain);
```

and menu creation method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

using this code i am able to implement menu but menu icon is sometime show and sometime not showing.

Comment: app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: @+id/language_menu is  not visible

Comment: nothing wrong in your code. set menu icon for submenu1,2,3.

Comment: Try calling `super` in your `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should still define the class [MenuInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuInflater.html) inside the `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042958/android-adding-a-submenu-to-a-menuitem-where-is-addsubmenu) post will help you find the answer.