# How could I implement a multilevel menu (dropdown) in android

Tags: android, android-layout, menu, submenu

I have to implement a menu like the following:

[image: Design]

I am currently using a nested menu in an item, but I can not make it look like the image.

Need to know how I can perform that cascade submenu effect shown to the right of the library menu item

How could I approach this problem?

I'm sorry for my English.

Comment: Try to use ExpandableListView, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38765790/default-navigation-drawer-view-to-expandablelistview

Comment: Thanks @MaxPinto, but the problem I have is that I do not know how to make the submenu look to the right of the parent menu, when you click on the parent (without this it disappears).

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml.
This is my xml for camera menu. One of the options allow changing the white balance. Within the white balance button, there a submenu of all the possible white balance settings. Hope this helped!

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/changeWhiteBalance"
        android:title="White Balance">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/changeToAutoWB"
                android:title="Auto">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/lockWB"
                android:title="Lock White Balance">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/changeToDirectSunlight"
                android:title="Direct Sunlight">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/changeToCloudy"
                android:title="Cloudy">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/changeToIncandescent"
                android:title="Incandescent">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/changeToFluorescent"
                android:title="Fluorescent">
            </item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/changeToTwilight"
                android:title="Twilight" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/changeToShade"
                android:title="Shade" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/changeToWarmFluorescent"
                android:title="Warm Fluorescent"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
```

Comment: The xml with the menu and the submenu I have it just as you tell me, but the problem I have is that I do not know how to do so when clicking on the Library item is shown on the right submenu.

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042958/android-adding-a-submenu-to-a-menuitem-where-is-addsubmenu