# how to add sub menu in android tv?

Tags: android, android-tv

I need to create a sub menu like in below image for android tv application. help me out.[image]

Comment: check this SO post related to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042958/android-adding-a-submenu-to-a-menuitem-where-is-addsubmenu/26432816

Comment: I need the solution for android tv.