# Add menu options programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to programmatically add options to my screen menu on Android, I saw several examples, but all aimed at a single button.

assuming I have.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
    menu.clear()

    // need add submenu this menu1
    // Menu1 (I do not what options the API will release for that user)
    val menu1 = menu
        .add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, null)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_round_white)
        .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)

    // need add submenu this menu2
    // Menu2 (I do not what options the API will release for that user)
    val menu2 = menu
        .add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, null)
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_edit_white)
        .setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM)

    // i want add submenuA in menu1 and submenuB menu2
}
```

I want to create submenu for these two buttons, one reason is that the options are served by my API, ie I have 2 buttons and for each button I have a list of options that comes from the server.

I can make a list for a button, but for 2 I did not find a solution.

Example: 
see my .GIF, I wanted a menu exactly like this (programmatically)

[image]

Comment: Do you want to create optionMenu for a button or your Whole activity??

Comment: i need submenu in 2 buttons in topbar

Comment: There might be something useful among the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543745/create-sub-menu-in-android-through-code), which you could adapt for Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your menu items and then set `PopupMenu` for each. Here's an example.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menu?.add(0,0,0,"Menu")?.setIcon(R.drawable.icon)?.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

and then:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
if (item?.itemId == 0) {
      val popup = PopupMenu(this, item.actionView)
      popup.menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, popup.menu)
      popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
         //do something with submenu
         true
      }
      popup.show() // show the popup
      return true
   }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

}
```

Comment: Think this is what you want. Right?